# How to substruct 15 days from a date column in the table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, informix

In the URL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cc7/3, it has schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE apsent
    (`day_id` int, `apssent_date` date);

INSERT INTO apsent
    (`day_id`, `apssent_date`)
VALUES
    (1, '2013-09-26'),
    (2, '2013-09-27')
;
```

I want to know how to update its apssent_date to the date substruct 15 days? I'm using Informix DB.

Comment: If you using Informix DB why you tag with mysql? the answers posted here aren't valid for informix!

Comment: I thought they are related things. They share some features.

Answer (score 2):

USE [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function, like this:

```
UPDATE `apsent` SET apssent_date = DATE_SUB(apssent_date, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc465/1

Answer (score 2):

In Informix it's

```
UPDATE apsent SET apssent_date = apssent_date -interval(15) day to day
```

In Mysql it's

```
UPDATE apsent SET apssent_date = DATE_SUB(apssent_date,INTERVAL 15 DAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my test at Informix , running the statement with dbaccess.

*Obs.The insert syntax used at the question isn't supported by Informix.*

```
$ DBDATE=y4md- dbaccess -e -a mydb x.sql

Database selected.
CREATE temp TABLE apsent
    (day_id int, apssent_date date);
Temporary table created.

INSERT INTO apsent (day_id, apssent_date) VALUES (1, '2013-09-26');
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO apsent (day_id, apssent_date) VALUES (2, '2013-09-27');
1 row(s) inserted.

INSERT INTO apsent (day_id, apssent_date) VALUES (2, '2013-01-01');
1 row(s) inserted.


select * , apssent_date - 15 units day from apsent ;

     day_id apssent_date (expression)
          1 2013-09-26   2013-09-11
          2 2013-09-27   2013-09-12
          2 2013-01-01   2012-12-17
3 row(s) retrieved.


update apsent set apssent_date = apssent_date - 15 units day ;
3 row(s) updated.


select * from apsent ;

     day_id apssent_date
          1 2013-09-11
          2 2013-09-12
          2 2012-12-17

3 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Informix:

UPDATE apsent
   SET apssent_date = apssent_date - 15